# Error page is not working on iis server

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, custom-error-pages

IIS server is not redirecting to the error page if the wrong url is not an .asp ending file.

Eg:

If the entered url is

http://domain.com/checking

The error page is not displayed, 
instead a default page of iis is displayed

If the url is   http://domain.com/checking.aspx

and the checking.aspx is not available, then the user gets directed to error page.

Need help with the webconfig of asp.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="404.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please update the post with the current config.

Comment: <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="404.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>